# Setting up a React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

All my questions become too convoluted, so i figured i'd ask like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3A7n.jpg

^ can this be done, and how do i do it?

I want to establish a react router, so it will update and remember url based on which page i'm on. I can't get it to work and it's driving me nuts :)

(only managed to do it directly from Paging.js, by wrapping buttons with < Link > tag and setting them directly to={/page/{api.id}} but that didn't work when i uploaded the app to github, because the browser didn't recognize the suffix as legit, so if i reloaded on /page/x it crashed and gave me 404. basically the link wasnt connected to anything, just gave a pseudo url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a react router dom hook called useParams()

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

const Page = () => {

  const { id } = useParams()

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Page id: {id}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Page
```

Comment: just directly inside App.js? I've tried your code and i get an error "Cannot read property 'match' of undefined"

Comment: @hackinghippie no, not inside the app component, in your page component. Leave your app component how it was previously.

Comment: so i've put it in Paging.js, since i can't use useParams in a class component. if i console.log the id, it's the right one!! oh wow, one step closer :D but is it normal for github pages to crash 404 when i reload on "page/3"?

Comment: @hackinghippie Yes, that's the normal behaviour of React Router: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually